# right-faded text optimization

Tags: c++, qt, optimization

I'd like to draw faded text (to the right), if the rendered `QString` `s` exceeds `rect.width()`. Currently I am doing:

```
inline void drawFadedLineText(QPainter* const painter, QRectF const& rect, 
  QColor const& color, QString const& s)
{
  painter->setPen(color);

  auto const fontMetrics(painter->fontMetrics());

  if (fontMetrics.width(s) > rect.width())
  {
    QPixmap pixmap(rect.size().toSize());

    pixmap.fill(Qt::transparent);

    {
      QPainter p(&pixmap);

      p.setFont(painter->font());

      p.drawText(0, fontMetrics.ascent(), s);

      static QLinearGradient lg;

      static bool init;

      if (!init)
      {
        init = true;

        lg.setStops(QGradientStops{
          qMakePair(qreal(0), QColor(0, 0, 0, 238)),
          qMakePair(qreal(1), QColor(0, 0, 0, 17))});
      }
      // else do nothing

      static auto const margin(qreal(10));

      auto const right(rect.width());

      lg.setStart(right - margin, qreal(0));
      lg.setFinalStop(right, qreal(0));

      p.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_DestinationIn);

      p.fillRect(QRectF(right - margin, 0, margin, rect.height()), lg);
    }

    painter->drawPixmap(rect.topLeft(), pixmap);
  }
  else
  {
    painter->drawText(QPointF(rect.left(),
      rect.top() + fontMetrics.ascent()), s);
  }
}
```

The problem with this approach is, that an extra layer (a `QPixmap`) is needed, but I can't use the composition mode `DestinationIn` with the text directly as the painter might have already been drawn upon with some background and fading the text would then fade that aswell. Does there exist a better way?

Comment: It's pointless to `inline` this method. The calls you make within will take quite long compared to the function call overhead. Don't inline unless you have measurements to show that it improves things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to skip the intermediate pixmap without having to draw the text multiple times. I'd hope that a pixmap is way more efficient than double rendering of the text.

About the only thing I'd do is to retain the `drawText` semantics. The implementation below tries to do it and to optimize by drawing the pixmap at integral coordinates within the target painter. Whether this improves the quality of the output is to be seen, but it can't hurt.

If you want to special-case a non-portable solution into the code, then it's worth noting that [`QBackingStore::paintDevice()` may happen to return a `QImage`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18725393/1329652). You could then add a specialized path in your code to access this, should it happen to be a `QImage`. Do note that you should use `dynamic_cast<QImage*>(backingStore()->paintDevice())` and revert to the code that uses a pixmap should that fail.

Another way of dealing with it would be to paint the entire widget to a pixmap, and only at the very end draw that pixmap on the widget. This can be further optimized if the backing store happens to be an image. That would give you additional flexibility if you have to have multiple accesses to the drawn-so-far contents. For cases where the backing store's paint device isn't a `QImage`, you'd probably want to turn off double buffering for the `QWindow`, and make further provisions for the widgets not to flicker in spite of absence of double buffering.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QFontMetrics>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QWidget>
#include <cmath>

//! Fractional part of the argument, with the same sign as the argument.
template <typename T> inline T fract(const T & x) { return x-trunc(x); }
//! A rectangle moved to the fractional part of the original topLeft()
template <> inline QRectF fract(const QRectF & r) { return QRectF(fract(r.x()), fract(r.y()), r.width(), r.height()); }
//! An integral size that contains the size of a given rectangle.
static QSize ceil(const QRectF & r) { return QSize(ceil(r.width()), ceil(r.height())); }
//! An integral point obtained by rounding `p` towards zero.
static QPoint truncint(const QPointF & p) { return QPoint(trunc(p.x()), trunc(p.y())); }

class Widget : public QWidget {
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) {
        static auto const text(QString(300, 'm'));
        QPainter p(this);
        p.setBrush(Qt::black);
        p.drawRect(rect());
        p.setPen(Qt::white);
        drawFadedLineText(&p, rect(), text);
    }
    // The semantics of `rect` and `s` are the same as in the call to `drawText(rect, s)`;
    void drawFadedLineText(QPainter* const painter, const QRectF & rect, const QString & s)
    {
        auto const fontMetrics(painter->fontMetrics());
        if (fontMetrics.width(s) <= rect.width()) {
            painter->drawText(rect, s);
            return;
        }

        static QLinearGradient lg;
        static bool init;
        if (!init) {
            init = true;
            lg.setStops(QGradientStops{
                            qMakePair(qreal(0), QColor(0, 0, 0, 238)),
                            qMakePair(qreal(1), QColor(0, 0, 0, 17))});
        }

        auto const margin(qreal(20.0));
        auto pixRect(fract(rect));
        auto const right(pixRect.right());
        lg.setStart(right - margin, 0.0);
        lg.setFinalStop(right, 0.0);

        QPixmap pixmap(ceil(rect));
        pixmap.fill(Qt::transparent);
        QPainter p(&pixmap);
        p.setPen(painter->pen());
        p.setFont(painter->font());
        p.drawText(pixRect, s);
        p.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_DestinationIn);
        p.fillRect(QRectF(right - margin, 0, margin, pixmap.rect().height()), lg);
        p.end();
        painter->drawPixmap(truncint(rect.topLeft()), pixmap);
    }
public:
    Widget() { setAttribute(Qt::WA_OpaquePaintEvent); setAttribute(Qt::WA_StaticContents); }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```