# Is there a way to access the image on the QWidget's backing store?

Tags: qt, qt5, qwidget

I'm doing some compositing inside the `paintEvent()` in a custom widget. Some of the compositing is done when some areas are already painted, and I need access to the current contents painted so far.

So, I'm looking for a way to access the image contents of the current backing store during a `paintEvent`. I've looked at [`QBackingStore`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qbackingstore.html), but there's nothing there that directly gives me access to the backing store bitmap. Is there some API, perhaps private, that could be used to provide that?

If not, I'll have to resort to painting on an explicit pixmap and rendering that pixmap onto the widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but it is not portable. The `QBackingStore` is just a wrapper class around a `QImage` buffer on most platforms, but I suppose this is not guaranteed. I've researched this issue when writing the `QuickWidget`. A cast is needed:

```c
QImage * image = dynamic_cast<QImage*>(backingStore()->paintDevice());
if (image != 0) // it's an image, do something with it
```

Be careful though not to cause the `QImage` to detach. Things such as resizing are off limits.

Check the `QuickWidget` out at:

https://code.google.com/p/quickwidget/

Comment: Your edit requires rtti support though :) Not guaranteed with Qt.

Comment: Also, if you know that a `static_cast` works, the `dynamic_cast` will just waste time and might not even be supported (with `-fno-rtti`).

Comment: Well, you don't know that static_cast works, that's the whole point (in your own words - it's not guaranteed). Not using rtti is unreasonable these days, I'd think. It's not "guaranteed" with Qt, but if you use it it's up to you to enable it. No big deal, I think.

Comment: @KubaOber I always compile `Qt` code with `-fno-rtti`. That's one of the appeals of `Qt`. No need for exceptions, no need for RTTI.

Comment: Note: This is only supposed to work from inside a `paintEvent`.