# create widget preview in Qt

Tags: qt

in Qt, is that possible to create temporary preview (a quick snapshot of GUI) of a widget just like the live taskbar preview in Windows7 (when we place our cursor on an item in the taskbar, a snapshot window shows on the top) ?
any ideas

Comment: `QPixmap::grabWidget`

Answer (score 2):

You can render a widget into an image using QWidget methods:

```
void    render(QPaintDevice * target, const QPoint & targetOffset = QPoint(), const QRegion & sourceRegion = QRegion(), RenderFlags renderFlags = RenderFlags( DrawWindowBackground | DrawChildren ))
void    render(QPainter * painter, const QPoint & targetOffset = QPoint(), const QRegion & sourceRegion = QRegion(), RenderFlags renderFlags = RenderFlags( DrawWindowBackground | DrawChildren ))
```

and use resulted QImage with desired size to show a preview to the user.

Answer (score 0):

As [evilruff has said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23133488/1329652), it's possible to render the widget into a paint device or a painter. You're paying the price for additional painting of the widget, of course.

Another option is to [grab the composited widget's backing store directly as a `QImage`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18724391/1329652). In Qt 5 this works on all platforms with exception of widgets backed by an OpenGL context.