# Qt C++ Can QGraphicsItem's paint() method access underlying pixels?

Tags: c++, graphics, qt4, qgraphicsitem

For visual markers in an imaging application on top of images I would like to enhance the contrast of said markers by using a fill color with high contrast to the local background (e.g. inverted). This requires for the object to read its background in a QGraphicsScene.

Is there an efficient (built-in) way of doing this or does it require something like rendering the scene without the marker, reading pixels in its position and then paint() the marker accordingly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to access the image on the QWidget's backing store in Qt 5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724391/is-there-a-way-to-access-the-image-on-the-qwidgets-backing-store-in-qt-5) The underlying pixels are not specific to the graphics-view framework, they are simply those of a widget's backing store.

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight way to get the rendered color of some point in QGraphicsScene. You should actually render the scene and see the color. One workaround is to render the scene to a QImage and pick the color from desired pixel:

```
QImage image=QImage(width,height,QImage::Format_RGB32);
QPainter painter( &image );
painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
myScene->render( &painter, image.rect(),QRectF(0,0,width,height), Qt::KeepAspectRatio );
painter.end();

QColor color = QColor(image.pixel(x,y));
```