# QImage to QPixmap is expensive

Tags: c++, qt

For my application, I wanted to show images continuously. But I found that it took me around 30ms to convert qimage to qpixmap. this affected my frame rate, so I want to find more effitive way to show my image with QtGui. Which method can I use?
Could someone help me?

Answer (score 3):

If you read the documentation well, everything is explained.

- QImage is design for IO handling, and for direct pixel access and manipulation
- QPixmap is designed and optimized for showing images on screen

If you only load image and show it (without any manipulation to your image), just load your image and cache it as QPixmap.

But if you do the manipulation, nothing much you can do. Maybe you can try to paint the image directly to QPainter of the widget. I don't know if it faster than convert image to pixmap and paint it to widget.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I seem to have a impression that drawing the image with painter is slower, but I will try it

Comment: Yes, drawing the QImage with painter is actually slower than converting it to QPixmap and drawing the pixmap (tested with Qt 5.4).

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do the conversion. Make sure that the image is in the format of the [backing store](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18724391/1329652), and simply `drawImage` on the widget. It's as fast as can be.

With the default raster backend, the `QPixmap` is a very thin wrapper around a `QImage`. As long as the image is of the correct format, the conversion is a no-op.

To obtain the format compatible with `QPixmap`, you can use the following code:

```
QImage::Format pixmapFormat() {
    static auto format = QPixmap{1,1}.toImage().format();
    return format;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem before and the best solution I have found is to use an **OpenGL** (`QOpenGLWidget` + `glDrawPixels()`) instead of converting `QImage` to `QPixmap`.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this method